# How to solve Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I have a Intellij Gradle project for HelloWorld. The program runs in the IDE but running the jar files with an invalid or corrupt jar error. I made several changes to the build.gradle and Manifest and still this does not run. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I think the issue is related to the manifest.

IDE -

Intellij - 2019.2
Gradle Project

```
Java - java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

build.gradle -

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.HelloWorldTesting'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

jar {
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Implementation-Title': 'Hello World',
                "Main-Class": "com.HelloWorldTesting.Hello"
        )
    }
    archivesBaseName = 'app'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Class -

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile HelloWorldArt.main.jar

tree -

```
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── main
│   │           └── Hello.class
│   └── tmp
│       └── compileJava
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
├── out
│   └── artifacts
│       ├── HelloWorldArt_jar
│       │   └── HelloWorldArt.jar
│       └── HelloWorldArt_main_jar
│           └── HelloWorldArt.main.jar
├── settings.gradle
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   ├── Hello.java
│   │   │   └── META-INF
│   │   │       └── MANIFEST.MF
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       └── resources
```

Comment: Can you try to remove from {configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect...} from jar section from gradle.

Comment: @Sambit - same error after that change.

Comment: Recreate the JAR file.

Comment: @user207421 works now, issue was two manifest files.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest you have defined your main class as `com.HelloWorldTesting.Hello`.
Looking at your project tree I can see that the Hello.java class is on your source folder root and is not in the package `com.HelloWorldTesting`.

Try setting your main class like this:
`"Main-Class": "Hello"`

Also you have a manifest file in your src folder **and** you are generating a manifest with gradle:

```
manifest {
    attributes(
            'Implementation-Title': 'Hello World',
            'Main-Class': 'Hello'
    )
}
```

Having multiple manifest files leads to this unexpected behaviour. Delete the manifest from your source folder, run `gradle clean` and the build should work after that.

Comment: same error - more details - trevor@trevor-Lenovo-YOGA-510-14AST:~/decent/HelloWorldArt$ find ./ -name MANIFEST.MF
./src/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
trevor@trevor-Lenovo-YOGA-510-14AST:~/decent/HelloWorldArt$ more ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Hello

trevor@trevor-Lenovo-YOGA-510-14AST:~/decent/HelloWorldArt - Not sure if the blank line makes a difference in the manifest at the end.

Comment: Have you tried the most basic version of the jar task without the "from" and "archivesBaseName"?

`jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Hello'
    }
}`

Comment: Also why do you have a manifest in your src folder if you generate it with gradle?

Comment: Michael Kleinmann - I specified the directory in the Build Artifact project structure as the src one, that was the default by Intellij. Should I change this? It seems to have two manifests now as I posted above. I think that could be one issue.

Comment: Ok I am not aware with these IntelliJ defaults. I just created a new gradle project in IntelliJ, added the Hello class under src/main/java and configured the jar task in the build.gradle like this:

`jar { manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'Hello' } }`

It builds and runs without any problem, so I would say you need to remove your manifest from the src folder because you are generating it with gradle.

Comment: Also what you specify in the IntelliJ project structure settings doesn't affect your gradle build. Everything gradle needs to know is taken from your `build.gradle` and the rest is convention over configuration.

Comment: worked!!! Solution - two manifests existed - I deleted both. Deleted at the cli in Ubuntu, also in Intellij, removed the src default and then regenerated, and that all worked.